# SwiftUi Create a Label and Multi Text Field not aligning properly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a TextField that is suppose to take both Short Text and Long Text which has a Label beside it but the label always hanging at the middle and not aligning tot the top. Tried every possible solution but none worked.

Scenario 1: Short Text

```
|-------|-------------------------------------------|
| Text  | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text          |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

Scenario 2: Long Text

```
|-------|-------------------------------------------|
| Text  | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the   |
|       | printing and typesetting industry. Lorem  |
|       | Ipsum has been the industry's standard    |
|       | dummy text ever since the 1500s           |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

This is what I always get below for long text, LABEL ALWAYS IN THE CENTER INSTEAD OF TOP. tried everything found online to no avail.

Scenario 2: Long Text

```
|-------|-------------------------------------------|
|       | Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the   |
|       | printing and typesetting industry. Lorem  |
| Text  | Ipsum has been the industry's standard    |
|       | dummy text ever since the 1500s           |
|---------------------------------------------------|
```

Code tried:

```
HStack {
    VStack {
        Text("Label: ")
            .lineLimit(1)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
        }
        .background(.teal)
                
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s ")
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        }
    .background(.tertiary)
}
.background(.blue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the layout like:

```
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) { //  Make texts aligned on the first line
    Text(title)
        .lineLimit(1)
        .background(.teal)

    Text(description)
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) //  Make the boxe fill the width to appear same size
        .background(.tertiary)
}
.background(.blue)
```

[image: Demo with multiple texts]